# A multiple choice input for a database as a string or integer?

Tags: database, database-design

If I have a database object that has a row that a user on a website can chose to be only a small number of predetermined options would it be bad practice to explicitly store these options, or would it be best to go for an integer?

Example:

A user has to fill in a form and one of the input questions is:

*Would you like:*

- type a
- type b
- type c

And that's it.

Would it be bad to store this as strings, ex. "type a"?

Would it be better to store the options as integers? 1, 2, 3 in this case.

If you think about memory, the answer is easy. If you think about overview, it's a different question, unless you have a very well structured mind of course.

The latter could of course be overcome if you make your own "admin space" or whatever in which the translation is made for you.

Anyhow, multiple choice questions. What is recommended?

Comment: I would store ints, but keep a lookup table in the dB for the values as well.  It's key should also include the question id/number.  This gives you the option later of even storing the questions in the dB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously opinion based, but here are my thoughts:

Would you ever want to change the description of the choices (without having to update your existing values)?  If so, a lookup table with integer ids would make sense (and your would store the integer for the responses).

Another consideration would be if you will ever need to provide the description in multiple languages.  If so, you would definitely want to key it with an integer.

Also, will the choices ever change?  Will you add type d and e?  Remove type a.  Again, a lookup table where choices could be enabled/disabled might be useful.

Comment: And sometimes the answers are mixed up the next time so one cannot memorize a/b/c (1/2/3).